# Manipulate object property of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with some property. I wanted to do some math on the object property, and expect to return an array as well.

I've tried, doesn't seems to work.

```
array.map(el => {
    el.count * 2;
    return el
})
```

```
array = [{
    count: 4,
    string: 'randomstring'
}, {
    count: 9,
    string: 'randomstring'
}, {
    count: 7,
    string: 'randomstring'
}, {
    count: 12,
    string: 'randomstring'
}]
```

Expected

```
array = [{
    count: 8,
    string: 'randomstring'
}, {
    count: 18,
    string: 'randomstring'
}, {
    count: 14,
    string: 'randomstring'
}, {
    count: 24,
    string: 'randomstring'
}]
```

Comment: Try `el.count *= 2;`.

Comment: You aren't setting it.

Comment: You even don't need a `map`. This can be achieved using `forEach`.

Answer (score 5):

`el.count * 2;` will not change the value of `el.count` You could assign it to it like

```
el.count = el.count * 2;
```

But this will create another problem. It will change the original data. So better to return a new object with modified `count` property using [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let array = [{ count: 4, string: 'randomstring' }, { count: 9, string: 'randomstring' }, { count: 7, string: 'randomstring' }, { count: 12, string: 'randomstring' }]

let res = array.map(el => ({...el,count:el.count*2}));
console.log(res);
```

You can also you [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let res = array.map(el => Object.assign({count:el.count*2}));
```

Comment: I would close this question as a typo.

Comment: It might be a typo, but it could be a lack of understanding. It's not clear which it is.

Comment: its a lack of understanding

Answer (score 3):

You could map independent objects without mutating the original array.

```
newArray = array.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { count: o.count * 2 }));
```

The same with spreading the object.

```
newArray = array.map(o => ({ ...o, count: o.count * 2 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without explicitly mutating object's value (that's why we use map, filter and reduce in the first place):

```
array.map(({ count, string }) => (
   { count: count * 2, string }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
array.map(e=>(e.count*=2,e))
```

```js
let array = [
    { count: 4, string: 'randomstring' },  
    { count: 9, string: 'randomstring' }, 
    { count: 7, string: 'randomstring' }, 
    { count: 12, string: 'randomstring' }
];

let r = array.map(e=>(e.count*=2,e))

console.log(r);
```

Comment: note that this way will mutate the original object.

Comment: yes of course - but OP not mention about immutable objects in question

Comment: But that is not the correct use of `map()` then. Its not expected that `map()` will change the real data. `map()` is not used to change the original array.

Comment: oh - I don't know it - can you provide proper link in ecma/js specification which state that?

Comment: I didn't mean that it can't be used. I mean it shouldn't be used like that. For that purpose `forEach` is best.

Comment: I understand your opinion but I ask about link